# ambiguity error with `reads` in ghc-7.8

Tags: haskell, ghc

I am testing the code for [Write yourself a Scheme in 48 hours](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Write_Yourself_a_Scheme_in_48_Hours/LaTeX#evaluator3.hs) with GHC-7.8.2, which gives me an error about ambiguity that I don't recall encountering in previous versions of GHC. 
The excerpt is below, with the problem line marked:

```
data LispVal = Atom String
             | List [LispVal]
             | DottedList [LispVal] LispVal
             | Number Integer
             | String String
             | Bool Bool
unpackNum :: LispVal -> Integer
unpackNum (Number n) = n
unpackNum (String n) = let parsed = reads n in  --problem line 
                          if null parsed 
                            then 0
                            else fst $ parsed !! 0
unpackNum (List [n]) = unpackNum n
unpackNum _ = 0
```

, and the error says:

```
No instance for (Read a0) arising from a use of ¡®parsed¡¯
The type variable ¡®a0¡¯ is ambiguous
Note: there are several potential instances:
  instance Read a => Read (Control.Applicative.ZipList a)
    -- Defined in ¡®Control.Applicative¡¯
  instance Read () -- Defined in ¡®GHC.Read¡¯
  instance (Read a, Read b) => Read (a, b) -- Defined in ¡®GHC.Read¡¯
  ...plus 26 others
```

If I change the problem line to

```
unpackNum (String n) = let parsed = reads n ::[(Integer,String)] in
```

then everything works fine.

I don't see why GHC failed to infer the type for ReadS from the signature of `unpackNum`. Can someone please explain what triggered the error?

(

-- EDIT --

Just some follow-up. From what I understand, the function type `unpackNum :: LispVal -> Integer` and the fact that `fst $ parsed !! 0` is a return value of it tells that `parsed` has type `[(Integer,b)]`, and from `type ReadS a = String -> [(a,String)]`, the `parsed` should be `[(a, String)]`. Shouldn't these two types unify to `[(Integer, String)]` and fix the type for `parsed`?

Can someone please explain why `NoMonomorphismRestriction` would break the above reasoning?

-- EDIT2 --

From the answers, I can understand how `NoMonomorphismRestriction` could cause the issue here. Still, what I don't understand is the fact that how this "two type for the same expression" behavior consistent with laziness in Haskell. In the example `parsed` or `reads n` is the same expression in one block and should be evaluated only once. How can it have type `a` the first time of evaluation and `Integer` the second time?

)

Thanks,

Comment: The code just compiles for me with ghc-7.8.2 ...

Comment: @kosmikus: Also on ghc-7.8.2 and I see the same error as the OP.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The types should unify but don't in the presence of the `NoMonomorphismRestriction` (as noted in the comments by @FedorGogolev and @kosmikus). However, the following more idiomatic approach removes the need for the type annotation in any case:

```
data LispVal = Atom String
             | List [LispVal]
             | DottedList [LispVal] LispVal
             | Number Integer
             | String String
             | Bool Bool
unpackNum :: LispVal -> Integer
unpackNum (Number n) = n
unpackNum (String n) = case reads n of
                           [] -> 0
                           ((x, _):xs) -> x
unpackNum (List [n]) = unpackNum n
unpackNum _ = 0
```

### The Difference Between Case and Null

It boils down to the fact that `null` is a function whereas `case` is straight syntax.

```
null :: [a] -> Bool
```

So with -XNoMonomorphismRestriction enabled, this is left as polymorphic as possible when the argument is supplied. The function doesn't restrict the argument type in any way, and so the compiler is unable to determine the return type of `reads`, causing the error. At the site of the function call, the type is ambiguous. In the case of the `case` statement, the compiler has the entire expression to work with, and so has the pattern matches to refine the return type of `reads`.

Comment: That was a fast downvote... care to share why? I'm happy to improve the answer if it's incorrect or needs improvement.

Comment: Why was this downvoted without comment? I can't see a problem with the answer. +1 to balance ;)

Comment: Thanks for the input. I don't know why the downvote. I do have a question though. (Correct me if I am wrong) `type ReadS a =  String -> [(a,String)]`, so the `snd` of the pair is known to be `String`, isn't it?

Comment: Ah yes, ok. I didn't realize that this is using `reads` and not `read`. Ugly code, by the way, using a check on `null` and then `!!` rather than pattern matching ...

Comment: Yep, I missed that as well. I'm going to mess around with this to see if I can rewrite in a way that removes the need for the type annotation since the information appears to be present.

Comment: Ok updated my answer to reflect your point. The type does unify now that we provide a little more structure for the type checker to work with. And notice that this code is much more idiomatic and doesn't rely on `null` or indexing into lists.

Comment: Tried a simplified version in `ghci`.

Comment: See `NoMonomorphismRestriction`.

Comment: @FedorGogolev -- Nope, that's not it either. The simplified version I posted still fails with -XNoMonomorphismRestriction enabled.

Comment: @acomar No, that's it. `NoMonomorphismRestriction` is indeed to blame. It's now enabled in GHCi by default.

Comment: @kosmikus: since 7.8? I wasn't aware of that.

Comment: Ok, so the real answer to the question is: If the monomorphism restriction is disabled, the definition of `parsed` gets a polymorphic type, namely `Read a => [(a, String)]`, and then the first use in `null parsed` doesn't have sufficient contextual information to resolve what `a` is. (Note what just happened: this actually *is* an example of where the monomorphism restriction is somewhat desirable. These situations are rare enough, but they happen ...)

Comment: Since you understand this better than I do, I'll delete my answer if you put up your own.

Comment: @acomar Added it as an answer, but I'd leave your answer available for reference, also because the pattern-matching version is actually the best solution IMHO.

Comment: @acomar Interesting, could you explain a bit more why pattern matching works while using `null` fails? I'd imagine that `null` is using some pattern matching internally.

Comment: @TingL I updated my answer with a couple of paragraphs explaining the issue.

Answer (score 6):

This is triggered if `NoMonomorphismRestriction` is active; which, btw, is now the case by default in GHCi since 7.8 [(see release notes, Section 1.5.2.3)](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.8.1/html/users_guide/release-7-8-1.html#idp5920480).

If the monomorphism restriction is disabled, the definition of `parsed` gets a polymorphic type, namely

```
parsed :: Read a => [(a, String)]
```

and then the first use in `null parsed` doesn't have sufficient contextual information to resolve what `a` is.

This happens to be one of the few cases where the monomorphism restriction actually does some good. Because with the polymorphic type, even if both use sites had sufficient type
information to resolve the class constraint, the actual parsing would happen twice.

The best *solution* is still to use pattern matching as suggested in acomar's answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Could you elaborate on why "null parsed doesn't have sufficient contextual information"? Please see my update in the question.

Comment: We have `null :: [b] -> Bool`, so `null parsed :: Read a => Bool`, i.e., it's a `Bool` once we make a choice for `a`. But there's no information available about what `a` is. As `parsed` is polymorphic, each use of `parsed` is allowed to pick a different type for `a`, so looking at the other use site doesn't help either. With the monomorphism restriction in place, this is exactly what happens: `parsed` is restricted to be monomorphic, so a choice for `a` must be found that works for all uses, and the `fst (parsed !! 0)` combo together with the `Integer` result type of `unpackNum` then does it.

Comment: Now I see. It is insane that two sites in the same let block can be treated as two instances where one binding has no influence on the other. I've upvoted your answer and accepted @acomar 's answer as you suggest that his case is the best solution (avoids the two-site issue). Thanks.

Comment: @TingL In this case it may appear weird to treat the two calls at two different instances. However, in some cases you do want to use two instances, e.g. `let f = ("value=" ++) . show in (f (length [1,2]), f 'a')`.

Comment: @TingL: Another example I ran into recently involved `read` itself. `read :: Read a => String -> a` so `read "11" :: Read a => a`. You can use this in two different contexts and have it return two different values despite referential transparency. So the compiler can't use the different use sites for `read` as evidence for a single monomorphic type after you've explicitly told it that it can't do that.

Comment: @chi In your example, it seems that f acts on two arguments of different types. What happens to lazy evaluation in Haskell in my example which means the same expression gets evaluated only once? If Haskell is truly lazy here, how can the same object (i.e. parsed or reads n) have two different types?

Comment: @TingL Think of a value with overloaded type as a function that takes an implicit argument. If you use it at a specific type, the implicit argument is passed and the function is applied. Sharing doesn't help here, as it is the function that is shared. This is precisely the reason why the monomorphism restriction was introduced all these years ago.

Comment: @kosmikus I can see why the monomorphism restriction makes sense here. I don't see how removing that restriction is ALSO correct. According to laziness, the expression 'reads n' is the same object, and is eval'ed only once, right? How can it be of two types logically?

Comment: @TingL A polymorphic value is of many types: `\x -> x` has type `Int->Int` and `Char->Char` and infinitely many others. Of course, `forall a. a->a` is its most general type. In Haskell also `1` is of types `Int`,`Integer`,`Double`,etc. The expression `read "11"` has types `Int`,`String`,`([Int],Char)`, etc. with most general type `Read a => a`. A polymorphic value is often visualized as a function from the set of all types into a concrete value. E.g. `\x->x` maps a type `a` into a function taking a value `x::a` and returning `x`. This is how you express polymorphism in System F, for instance.

Comment: @chi Still, if I understand laziness right, 'read n' is one object as it will be evaluated only once. I don't see how it can have two types. I am not familiar with System F, and can't speak about that. Do you mean that per System F, e.g., in evaluating '(read "11",read "11")' the term 'read "11"' is evaluated twice?

Comment: @TingL In Haskell `(read "11",read "11")` evaluates the `read "11"` twice in a context which chooses e.g. the type `(Int,String)`. Note that it does not produce the same value: one is an integer while the other is a string. In System F you would write something like `(read Int "11", read String "11")` making it clear that the two `read` calls have different arguments. In Haskell (and in most FP languages) these type arguments are implicit, and the compiler inserts them for you during type inference. Eventually, the two `read` uses causes two completely different pieces of code to be executed.

Comment: @chi, then I take it that this is also the case for 'let x = read "11" in (x,x)" ? i.e. (as with 'parsed' in the OP) the two 'x' are two different functions calls. If so, I think the 'let' syntax in Haskell should be abolished as it hugely misleading as what appears to name one thing is actually referring to one among a set of objects.

Comment: Also, I just read that System F is strongly normalizing. I vaguely remember that this means that the same expression needs to be eval'ed only once, and that's why we can use 'let' binding as if we are assigning expressions to temporary variables in imperative languages, isn't that the case?

Comment: @TingL Yes, but it's not just `let`. If you define at the top level `x = read "11"` and then use it as `(x,x) :: (Int,String)` you will get two "calls" to `x`. This is just how polymorphism works: do you expect `case (id,id) of (f,g) -> (f "xyz", g 'a')` to fail? Or to use identity at two different types? TBH, in the case of `read` things are more complex since _restricted_ polymorphism is involved, but you should get the point.

Comment: @chi this is interesting. I wonder what happened to laziness here. How can Haskell tell when to evaluate an expression only once and when to evaluate it in every instance. But I get your point.

Comment: @TingL Strong normalization is unrelated: it just states that every term will reach normal form, provided you perform enough beta reduction steps, with any evaluation strategy. Haskell is not strongly normalizing, BTW, since it allows one to write `let f x = f x in f 0`, which System F can not express.

Comment: @TingL That's a good question. First, note that the Haskell report just specifies what should be the final result, and not how it should be computed. Being everything side-effect-free, this leaves a LOT of room to the compiler. GHC makes sensible choices, choosing to make two calls evaluating `(f 3, f 3)` but only one for `let x = f 3 in (x,x)`, _provided_ the result of `f 3` is monomorphic. The monomorphism restriction forces this, making the two expressions non equivalent (the second one has fewer types). This may be good or bad depending on the context.

Comment: @TingL Note two things: First, Haskell's semantics don't specify if something is evaluated once or several times. Second, the overloaded term is internally a function, and the function is evaluated only once. At every use site, the function is applied. So `let x = read "11" in (read "11" :: Int, read "11" :: Float)` is not much different from `let x = (+1) in (x 2 :: Int, x 2 :: Float)`.

Comment: Well, years ago when I first read Haskell tutorials, I read that it was unnecessary to use let bindings to save computation, e.g. as in 'let x=x1-x2 in x*x' as you would have done in C++ because of laziness. It seems that's not universally true. It's good to know.

Comment: Also, the examples you show suggest not only the fact 'let' does not necessarily save computation, but also that 'let' shouldn't be considered as equivalents of assignment in imperative languages such as C++. It's more like the equivalents of macros in the imperative world where you think you defined a thing until you realize otherwise when you place the name in a context.

Comment: @TingL I think all of this leads a bit far, but: (1) In GHC, a `let` introduces sharing, and you can use `let` to save computation. GHC does not usually do common subexpression elimination, so `let x = fib 3000 in x + x` is better than `fib 3000 + fib 3000`. (2) I have no idea how you get the idea that `let` could be similar to assignment. It assigns a name to a subcomputation and introduces sharing. Macros typically are re-evaluated every time you use them, `let`-bindings are not.

Comment: @kosmikus The similarity is only formal. As you said, there is the saving-computation part, which is what assignment gives you in imperative languages: you compute and assign the result to a variable and only do one computation. There is also the fact that macros being evaluated every time of use, which is exactly what happened to 'let parsed = read n' in the OP. Indeed, this is a bit too far.